# Finding in elements in a tuple and filtering them

Tags: python

Assuming I have a tuple like:

```
[('text-1','xxx'), ('img-1','iii'), ('img-2','jjj'), ('text-2','xxx')]
```

I want to filter out the list and produce a new one with elements that begin with 'img'. So my new list will look like:

```
[('img-1','iii'), ('img-2','jjj')]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 55, accepted):

One way:

```
>>> l = [('text-1','xxx'), ('img-1','iii'), ('img-2','jjj'), ('text-2','xxx')]
>>> [t for t in l if t[0].startswith('img')]
[('img-1', 'iii'), ('img-2', 'jjj')]
```

Another way:

```
>>> filter(lambda x: x[0].startswith('img'), l)
[('img-1', 'iii'), ('img-2', 'jjj')]
```

The first is called a list comprehension. See [F.C.'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7100243/finding-in-elements-in-a-tuple-and-filtering-them/7100289#7100289) for a related technique. The basic syntax is `[{expression} for {item_var_or_vars} in {iterable} if {boolean_expression}]`. It's semantically equivalent to something like this:

```
new_list = []
for {item_var_or_vars} in {iterable}:
    if {boolean_expression}:
        new_list.append({expression})
```

The `if {boolean_expression}` bit is optional, just as it is in the for loop.

The second is simply the built-in function `filter`, which accepts a test function and an iterable, and returns a list containing every element that "passes" the test function. `lambda`, if you haven't seen it before, is just a quick way of defining a function. You could do this instead:

```
def keep_this_element(element):
    return element[0].startswith('img')   # returns True for ('img...', '...')

new_list = filter(keep_this_element, l)   # keeps only elements that return True
```

Comment: This is great. Is there a name for both of these techniques? I would like to do more reading on these methods. Thanks.

Comment: The first is a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) the second is [filter](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#filter) and a [lambda expression](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#lambda)

Comment: Thanks. This is so insightful.

Answer (score 13):

Something like this perhaps?

```
l2 = [item for item in l1 if item[0].startswith('img')]
```

Answer (score 6):

Just another way with [generator expression](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) (it could make some difference on large lists)

```
>>> l = [('text-1','xxx'), ('img-1','iii'), ('img-2','jjj'), ('text-2','xxx')]
>>> (x for x in l if x[0].find('img') == 0)
0: <generator object <genexpr> at 0x917a00>
>>> gen = (x for x in l if x[0].find('img') == 0)
>>> list(gen)
1: [('img-1', 'iii'), ('img-2', 'jjj')]
```

Answer (score 4):

With Normal Loop

```
input = [('text-1','xxx'), ('img-1','iii'), ('img-2','jjj'), ('text-2','xxx')]
inp = []
for i in input:
    if 'img' in i[0]:
        inp.append(i)
print(inp)
```

or by Using lambda function

```
inp = list(filter(lambda x: 'img' in x[0],input))
 print(inp)
```

or by Using List Comprehension

```
 inp = [i for i in input if 'img' in i[0]]
 print(inp)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
tuple_filter = lambda t, i, w: filter(lambda a: a[i].startswith(w), t)
newtuple = tuple_filter(thetuple, 0, 'img')
```